# AppBarLayout does not always re-enter on scroll down

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I created a collapsing transparent search bar using AppBarLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout inside a CoordinatorLayout and a RecyclerView. It was a bit (lot) tricky to have the recyclerView appear behind the appBarLayout instead of below it ; but is working.    My problem is that sometimes, the app bar does not re-enter when I scroll down. I simply stays invisible outside of the screen. Here is my layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="88dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/services_recycler_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="88dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/color_transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Location or Service"
    android:id="@+id/button_search_bar"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help on solving the not re-entering issue would be great.

A side problem, is that because I am using the `app:behavior_overlapTop="88dp"` to make recyclerView appear behind the app bar, the whole scrolling is a little odd : it starts by scrolling the appBar and then scrolls the recycler view. Any better solution is welcome.

**EDIT :**
I realized that the AppBar actually re-enter on scroll down but is invisible (I can click on it, I just can't see it). I figured I would share this new clue =)

Comment: Is there a reason why the RecyclerView's visibility is gone?

Comment: yes sorry I will remove this it does not belong here. It is part of the old version of the view. I was handling it in the code after the loading of my items.

Comment: how did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer i just want to confirmation that what  you give, it will look like this?? on scroll up

[image]

means that Search button will come on top?

Edit:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

add exitUntilCollapsed flag.

Comment: The search button must completely disappear on scroll up and re-enter on scroll down. And when the search button is visible, the list must be visible behind it too. The search bar must be overlaying the list. So what you are showing is not what I am looking for.

Comment: It does not change anything. And now I have moved to support v 23.1.1 and build tool 23.0.2 the overlapping does not work anymore. I've build my own implementation from scratch it is better. I'll keep the bounty open to see if anyone else is interested and can provide more info. But if no one else wants it, remind me in 2 days to give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trial and error I managed to find a solution to your problem. You can set an `OnScrollListener` to your `RecyclerView`. Inside the listener you check if in `onScrolled` the first item of the `RecyclerView` is on screen.
If the first item is visible, first you change the visibility of your `AppBarLayout` to `View.INVISIBLE` and secondly you change it directly back to `View.VISIBLE`.

Your code may look like this (Kotlin) :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    contentView(R.layout.my_activity)

    val mAppbar = appbar
    val mServices_recycler_view = services_recycler_view

    //...

    mServices_recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView : RecyclerView, newState : Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            }



        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView : RecyclerView, dx : Int, dy : Int) {
                val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager::class.java.cast(recyclerView.layoutManager)
                if(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                mAppbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                mAppbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
    }
}
```

I am aware of the fact, that this is not very beautiful, but as long as it solves the issue I don't mind.
Additionally you want to improve the check if the first item of the `RecyclerView` is shown, so that it won't trigger everytime you scroll, even when it is only a little bit.

The layout you described in your question does not have to be changed.